# Post de valores numa Listbox sem estarem selecionados

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

É possível fazer um Post dos valores de uma `Listbox` sem que eles estejam Selecionados?

A minha ListBox:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCatequistas, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.SelectedCatequistas, "PessoaID", "Nome"), htmlAttributes: new
                           {
                               @class = "form-control",
                               Size = 15,
                               style = "width: 100%;"
                           })
```

Comment: Se você monta a listbox com os valores vindos do servidor porque você quer envia-los de volta? Eles já estão lá.

Comment: Quando edito os valores se não os seleccionar ele não chegam ao controlador.